# installing xubuntu on eee pc 900a using unetbootin

Tags: xubuntu

I am attempting to install xubuntu on my eee pc 900a using unetbootin. after making sure the boot sequence is right and save & exit i get a blue screen with the header "unetbootin and in the box "default". and reading "press tab or automatic boot will start" with a countdown. but once it reaches 1 it starts the count all over again. like in a loop. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making bootable USB using windows, try using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.6.exe). For me it worked better than uNetbootin. And if you are making bootable USB using any Ubuntu machine, you can use [Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/usb-creator-gtk/).

Comment: Yes, unetbootin can be problematic. Take a look at this official guide about creating USB with ubuntu (just use xubuntu ISO instead): http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows